# how to scroll 2 divs separately using full height of browser

Tags: css, html, scroll

I have 2 divs next to each other in one row. I want the user to scroll them  vertically separated when the content overflows the div and I also want to use the full height of the current browser window.

Here with a fixed height of 700px:

[image: with a fixed height of 700px]

But when i use

```
height:auto;
```

or

```
height:100%;
```

there is no separate scrolling. (the grey div has a lot of more text down) it only has the main scroll and looks like:

[image: dynamic height]

Here the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}


#maintest {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:700px;
    background-color:grey;
}

#discussion {
    float:none;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    background-color:#B0D1E1;
}

  </style>

<body>

    <nav>
        <a href="test">testlink</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="maintest">
     <?php include "text.html" ?>
    </div>

     <div id="discussion">
     <?php include "text.html" ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) instead of direct percentages:

```
.column {
  height: 100vh; /* percent relative to viewport height */
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Here's [a working example of what you're trying to accomplish](http://jsbin.com/dorofa/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 1):

That's because you should update the width and height for both divs from `px` to `vh`.

`1 vh` is relative to **1%** of the **viewport's height**.

Here is the updated CSS code:

```
#maintest {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    height:20vh;
    width:20vw;
    background-color:grey;
}

#discussion {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    height:20vh;
    width:20vw;
    background-color:#B0D1E1;
}
```

Here is an example I made to show how **`vh`** works.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/u2zfxaai

Answer (score 0):

copy this style

```
    #maintest {
        float:left;
        display:block;
        overflow-y:scroll;  //scroll appear when it exceeds max-height
        max-height:100vh;  //set your maximum-height 
        width:40%;         //half the window
        background-color:grey;
    }

    #discussion {
        float:right;
        display:block;
        overflow:scroll;
        max-height:100vh;
        width:60%;
        background-color:#B0D1E1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

.div1 {
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 40%;
}

.div2 {
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: This might be the best to develop fullheight webapps with a list and detail view

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with based on the design of Microsoft's OneDrive. This works for me based on my requirements and I thought someone else might have the same requirements and this could help them.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .position-absolute {
            position: absolute;
        }
        .position-relative {
            position: relative;
        }
        .overflow-auto {
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .d-flex {
            display: flex;
        }
        .flex-direction-column {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .flex-direction-row {
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .flex-grow-1 {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .vh-100 {
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .h-100 {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .w-100 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .bg-red {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .bg-blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .bg-green {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-direction-column h-100">
        <div class="">top content</div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-direction-row flex-grow-1">
            <div class="bg-red position-relative flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
                <div class="position-absolute overflow-auto h-100 w-100">
                    one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> one <br/> 
                </div>
                

            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue position-relative flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
                <div class="position-absolute overflow-auto h-100 w-100">
                    two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> two <br/> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>bottom content</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This way you can have a header and footer section respectively above and below the two columns and still the browser scroll(not the columns' scrolls) won't get enabled, the same is true if you remove header or footer or both.