# How to scroll only mouse pointer content on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]

Consider that my mouse positioned on **Sidebar** and I use the mouse wheel to scroll to the bottom or top of **Sidebar**. When I reach the bottom of **Sidebar** and keep scrolling with the wheel, it will begin to scroll **Main Content**. I would like the mouse wheel to only scroll the current div that the cursor is sitting on.

Is this possible with CSS? Or do I need to wire up JS/jQuery events to detect the div I am currently on and stop the scroll event? I am hoping there is a CSS solution to this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: May you share an [mcve] of how this is built so far?

Comment: Noticed a similar post answered already. Please check if this post solves your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169383/how-to-scroll-2-divs-separately-using-full-height-of-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work with regular CSS. Try handling both sections as separat containers.
Here is a simplified example i built based on your illustration:

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
}

.main-content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgb(139, 139, 139);
}

.content {
  height: 500vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
 <div class="sidebar">
  <div class="content">Sidebar</div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="content">Main Content</div>
</div>
```